# how to include directory based on condition in cmake

Tags: c, gcc, cmake-language

I am using windriver compile. I followed below steps

```
set(var_1)
if(var_1)
 target_include_directories(cfar  PRIVATE ${APP_DIR}/z7b/variant_1)
else
 target_include_directories(cfar  PRIVATE ${APP_DIR}/z7b/variant_2)
endif()
```

Comment: Why tooltip? What problem do you  have? Format your code

Comment: @0___________, I already removed it. ;)

Comment: You didn't describe the problem. Please [edit] your question and add more details: What happens or what error occurs? What do you want to happen? How do you detect that it's not working?